# Combing ScrollView's adjustPan and adjustResize feature

Tags: android, scrollview, padding, adjustpan

I am facing an issue in Scrollview.On Keyboard input of Bottommost EditText, I want adjustPan feature to occur and that is working fine if I use `"stateHidden|adjustPan"` in Manifest file. The problem is if I click on any middle element of scrollbar and when the keyboard pops up I am not able to fully scroll down. I fixed this issue by using adjustResize but then I cant use adjustPan along with it so that my bottommost element gets automatically pushed up so that the user can see.

Please note: I have added `android:paddingBottom` and it has not been helpful here.

Comment: do it programmatically ... i.e when different edittext gets focus use listners and set adjustPan adjustResize based on that